# Использование свойств в С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

В С++ для атрибутов класса можно задавать свойства, шаблон определения которых -

```
__declspec( property( get=get_func_name, put=put_func_name ) ) declarator
```

Есть класс, суть которого - работа с координатами

```
class Object
{
public:
    __declspec(property(get = getX, put = putX)) unsigned x;
    __declspec(property(get = getY, put = putY)) unsigned y;
private:
    unsigned getX() const { return _x; }
    unsigned getY() const { return _y; }
    void     putX(unsigned x) { _x = x; }
    void     putY(unsigned y) { _y = y; }

    unsigned _x, _y;
};
```

И при попытке использовать его

```
int main()
{
    Object a;
    a.x = 0;
}
```

получаю ошибку

"Object::putX: невозможно обратиться к private-члену".

Если сделать методы публичными, ошибка пропадает, как и часть мотивации использовать свойства: с таким же успехом можно использовать и сами методы. Есть вариант избежать ошибки, оставив методы, как и атрибуты, недоступными в дальнейшей работе с классом?

Comment: Ну, это не "в C++", это *Microsoft Specific*... Вариантов нет: вы хотите и наружу не показать, и при этом снаружи использовать... Это уже какое-то "у меня для вас посылка, но я вам ее не дам" :) Или - еще точнее - открыть сейф ключом, который лежит в сейфе... А вообще - лично мое мнение - как вы написали, *с таким же успехом можно использовать и сами методы* - лучше и в самом деле их использовать, не полагаясь на расширения конкретного компилятора...

Comment: @Harry
Заинтересовала идея свойств в C++. Какое-никакое увеличение скорости разработки, улучшение читабельности кода.. Тем более сам __declspec определен внутри класса. Почему бы и нет.

Comment: Ну, я же написал - *личное* мнение. Не люблю никакие нестандарты. И люблю самодокументируемый код :) В принципе то же самое можно сочинить и без свойств, на чистом С++, но мне кажется, что такое присвоение - типа `a.x = 0;` - будет только затуманивать код - будет казаться, что здесь открытый член-данные, и обычное присваивание... Да и вообще, это уже какое-то нарушение принципа инкапсуляции - выставление наружу внутренностей класса, нет?

Comment: @Harry
Идея свойств состоит в регулировании взаимодействий с атрибутами. Это же и есть инкапсуляция. При том не приходится использовать методы - можно работать напрямую, не опасаясь, что что-то пойдёт не так. Если к ним привыкнуть, программировать будет удобнее

Comment: И как по-вашему будет работать гетер этого свойства, если он непубличный? "*с таким же успехом можно использовать и сами методы*" - `__declspec( property` именно это и делает - вместо обращения к полю вставляет вызов геттера / сеттера

Comment: @VTT
Свойство определено внутри класса, как обычный публичный метод, который может взаимодействовать с приватными элементами. Тогда

`a.x = 0;`

интерпретировалось бы как публичный метод с аргументом 0, внутри которого уже бы вызывался приватный сеттер. С геттером было бы тоже самое, но чуть проще - без аргументов. В теории должно быть нечто подобное

Comment: Если привыкнуть - то можно и на ассемблере программировать. Или на Jave. Только при чем тут тогда C++?...

Comment: У вас немного странное понимание проэктирования класса. В ооп считается, что у класса есть состояние. И после инициализации состояние должно быть всегда валидными. Это совокупность требований таких как переменная capacity хранит ровно столько сколько выделено или, например, глубина дерева не больше 2*log2(size). Публичным должны быть те методы, которые не портят состояние класса. Приватными те, которые могут испортить. И у вас property и соответствующий метод могут либо одновременно портить, либо обновременно не портить состояние. Поэтому они должны иметь одинаковый уровень доступа.